# You can't run a function when defining an object property?

Tags: php, oop

The code in question...

```
class MyClass
{
    public $template_default = dirname(__FILE__)."/default.tpl";
}
```

Why do I get the following error when I try to use the `dirname()` function when defining an object property?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in ...
>   blah blah blah

I guess object properties are not like PHP variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at **compile time** and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Since `dirname` is a run-time function, it should be called in the constructor of the Object. So, set `$template_default` in the object constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    public $template_default;

    public function __construct(){
         $this->template_default = dirname(__FILE__). "/default.tpl";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that about defining properties before.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.6, you can do the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $template_default = __DIR__."/default.tpl";
}
```

PHP 5.6 allows simple scalar math and string concatenation in initialization now ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)), and `__DIR__` is the same thing as `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Otherwise, Drakes' answer is correct.